# Why was the bracelet left behind?

Tags: the-thousand-worlds, nightflyers

I'm not sure if this can be *answered* or merely discussed, but I hope there is a logical answer.

I just watched the end of Season 1 (of 1 currently) of George R.R. Martin's *Nightflyers* and I think it generally makes sense, apart from one detail.

> Without going into too much detail, I get that Dr. Karl D’Branin was transported to a universe where his daughter, Skye, didn't die from the disease plaguing Earth.
>  
>  But I don't get why the bracelet was left behind. Surely she would have still made that for him. I feel connected to the daughter side of the story, as one of my daughters is the same age as Skye and yes, she makes me bracelets with animals hanging off them. But I feel I may have missed a reason for it being left behind?